# AWS database connection refused

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, networking

I created a `postgresql` instance on `aws`, and I made it publicly accessible. Also, I set both the inbound and outbound `0.0.0.0/0` in security group.

However, I cannot connect to this remote instance with my local computer. I also tried:

```
telnet <end point> 5432
```

It raised error:

> telnet: connect to address xxx: Connection refused
>   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

What is the possible reason?

### Update:

[image]

In the `VPC`:

[image]

In the `subnets`:

[image]

In the `route tables':

[image]

and its `routes`:

[image]

the `internet gateway`:

[image]
Finally, the `security group`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not just sufficient to select the "Publicly accessible" option and security group of RDS/DB. In addition, like any other instance it needs the ability (connected to Internet Gateway) and route to it.

The following document provides clear instructions for your DB/RDS to be accessible over the internet.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html#USER_VPC.Scenario4

Comment: I also configed the `VPC`, and `subnets` are attached to it.  These subnets have a global route  `0.0.0.0/0 -> internet gateway`. But it still does not work.